# Can't create custom labels with XlsxWriter

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am trying to add custom data Labels into a "column chart" with the XlsxWriter version: 1.2.1.
No matter what, it never displays custom labels but always the current values.

Like this chart with current values:

[image: Chart with current Values]

I already tried to copy some example code from here:

[Chart data label position is ignored for custom data labels · Issue #754](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/754)

The chart should look like this:

[image: example chart]

But when I execute it, it shows up like this:

[image: a different chart]

Does somebody have any solution? Is it because of the version?
P.S. I'm working on my work computer in the office — that's why I can't update the library that easily.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for custom data labels was added in XlsxWriter [version 1.3.2](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/changes.html). It wasn't supported in the version you have (1.2.1). So you will need to upgrade the library version to at least 1.3.7 but preferably to the latest version.

Comment: Okay, as i expected... Thank you for the fast respond